# How to count how many points are in a quadrant of the cartesian plane?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, cartesian-coordinates

I have the following points in the cartesian plane:

```
points = [(4, 5), (-0, 2), (4, 7), (1, -3), (3, -2), (4, 5), (3, 2), (5, 7), (-5, 7), (2, 2), (-4, 5), (0, -2),(-4, 7), (-1, 3), (-3, 2), (-4, -5), (-3, 2), (5, 7), (5, 7), (2, 2), (9, 9), (-8, -9)]
```

And I want to know how many of them are in each quadrant. If x or y are 0, the point is not in any quadrant.

So far I have done this:

```
Q1=0
Q2=0
Q3=0
Q4=0
Any_quadrant=0

for (x,y) in points:
    if (x>0 & y>0):
        Q1+=1
    elif (x<0 & y>0):
        Q2+=1
    elif (x<0 & y<0):
        Q3+=1
    elif (x>0 & y<0):
        Q4+=1

else:
    x==0 | y==0
Any_quadrant+=1

print(Q1)
print(Q2)
print(Q3)
print(Q4)
print(Any_quadrant)
```

But the sum of the points in each quadrant is not happening and I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: You shouldn’t have a condition with your else clause.  Remove the `x==0 | y==0` and fix the indentation to align...  perhaps that is just formatting here

Comment: please use `and` instead of `&`, they are not the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses `and` instead of && and `or` instead of ||. In python & and | are bitwise operators, not boolean operators. Furthermore `else` statements do not include conditions so you need to remove that.

As a style note, in python variables should not have capital letters unless they are the names of classes or are constants.